# How to correctly chain async functions?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, typescript, babeljs

I'm using async functions in ES7, with TypeScript, webpack and babel. The major libraries and frameworks are `express` and `sequelize`.

The critical configurations are:

**.babelrc:**

```
{
    "stage": 0,
    "optional": "runtime"
}
```

**webpack.config.js:**

```
{test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'babel-loader!ts-loader', exclude: /node_modules/},
```

**tsconfig.json:**

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": true,
        "target": "es6",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "experimentalAsyncFunctions": true
    },
    "files": [
    ]
}
```

And I am using `async` as:

```
async function getCommentsOfVideoById(videoId: string): any {
    let commentData;
    ServiceLogger.info(`[VideoService]: fetching comment data.`);
    commentData = await VideoComment.findAll({
        where: {
            vid: videoId
        }
    });
    return commentData;
}
```

And call it as:

```
asyncRouter.get('/test/async/vservice', async(req, res) => {
    const videoService = new VideoService();
    ServiceLogger.info(`[VideServiceTest]: fetching comment data.`);
    let data111;
    try{
        data111 = await getCommentsOfVideoById('48');
    } catch (e) {
    } finally {
        console.log('No error');
        console.log(data111);
    }
    res.send(data111);
});
```

But what is returned and sent is simply `[ [Function] ]`, which I don't quite understand. And the log inside `getCommentsOfVideoById`, which is `[VideoService]: fetching comment data.`, is never outputed.

What confuses me is that similar usages are actually valid. For example, I wrote a wrapper for the `http` function with `bluebird`:

```
function httpGetAsync(options) {
    return new bluebird.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        console.info(`downloading from ${options}`);
        http
            .get(options, (res) => {
                let data = '';
                res.on('data', function (chunk: string) {
                    console.info('==========================');
                    console.info(chunk);
                    console.info('==========================');
                    data += chunk;
                });
                res.on('end', function () {
                    resolve(data);
                });
            })
            .on('error', reject);
    });
}
```

And tested with a chained calling of async functions:

````
async function a(url: string) {
    console.log('[a]: start');
    let result;
    try {
        result = await httpGetAsync(url);
        //result = await divide(2, 3);
        //await Promise.delay(1000);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('[a]: Exception', e);
    } finally {
        console.log('[a]: result', result);
    }
    console.log('[a]: end');
    return result;
}
```

```
asyncRouter.get('/test/async/nesting', async(req, res) => {
    console.log('[/test/async/nesting]');
    const url = req.query.url ? req.query.url : 'http://google.com/';
    let response;
    try {
        response = await a(url);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('[/test/async/nesting]: Exception', e);
    } finally {
        console.log('[/test/async/nesting]: response', response);
    }
    res.send(response);
});
````

And it works as expected (when you access `http://domain/test/async/nesting?url=somewhat` you get redirected).

The curious thing is, both `sequelize` and my code uses `bluebird`, which should be (and proves to be) compatible with `await`. Looking at the type definitions of `findAll` and `Promise`, they all have the same type signature:

```
///sequelize.d.ts
findAll( options? : FindOptions ) : Promise<Array<TInstance>>;
///bluebird.d.ts
declare class Promise<R> implements Promise.Thenable<R>, Promise.Inspection<R> {
    constructor(callback: (resolve: (thenableOrResult: R | Promise.Thenable<R>) => void, reject: (error: any) => void) => void);
}
```

So the problem does not seem to lie here. But what is the actual problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be name collision of `import * from bluebird as Promise` with ES6 native `Promise`. When I renamed that import to `bluebird`, all things worked as expected.